# Where in the event log is the IIS AppPool recycling events being recorded?

Tags: windows, iis, windows-event-log, application-pools, eventviewer

I turned on all the options for IIS AppPool recycling logging and recycled the app pool a few times and I am not seeing the events in the event log. I refreshed a few sections in the event log. Where are these being recorded? Windows 7.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Event viewer / Custom views / Server Roles / Web Server (IIS)

Comment: That option exists in Windows Server, not Windows 7. I just created a custom view with event sources which start with 'IIS' and it didn't log the apppool recycling. Not sure which event source I should select.

Comment: The source should be WAS @Tony_Henrich

Comment: Created one on WAS, recycled a pool, refreshed the new log and there was nothing new in there.

Answer (score 1):

Just to test, I did enabled same options for an app pool and imediately **Microsoft-IIS-Configuration/Operational** registered some events stating that there have been made some changes to the application pool.

Just to note, that log was already enabled, so make sure it's enabled before doing changes to app-pool